# Is it possible to cut out a full width horizontal section of on image so that the rest of the image moves up?

Tags: gimp

I have many web pages that are saved as image files.  I need to remove certain horizontal sections entirely and move the rest of the content up.

I have been doing this by selecting, dragging, cutting and moving but it is a bit fiddly to get everything to line up and also because the images are very long it can take a long time.

Is there an easier way to remove a horizontal section (the whole width) of an image?

Comment: I don't believe there's anything automated to do this for you. The application would have no idea what/where to cut and what to line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two scripts that you will find [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)(*):

1. With `ofn-guillotine-layer`: put horizontal guides to bracket the part that you want to remove, and call the script (`Layer>Guillotine`). It will create layers for each horizontal strip delimited by guides.
2. Hide or delete the layers you don't want to keep (this includes your initial layer)
3. With `arrange-layers`: `Image>Arrange layers>Space>Vertically` and give a space of `0`. This will abutt all the visible layers.
4. `Image>Merge visible layers`. You can ask it to delete the invisible layers.
5. `Image>Zealous crop` to resize the image.

(*) `ofn-guillotine-layers.zip` and `arrange-layers-0.2.py`. Instructions to install them are at the bottom of the page. If you use them often you can set keyboard shortcuts for them.

Answer (score 1):

I also found cutout.py from https://github.com/akkana/gimp-plugins which also does a good job.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this:

1. Select the region of the image you want to remove with the select tool
2. Press the delete key to delete this section
3. Under Image menu choose "zealous crop"